# Value returns NaN

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to return the difference between the dates but it keeps returning NaN.

I have the following code:

```js
startDate = "11/30/2018";
presentDate = "12/6/2018";       
endDate = "12/30/2019";
var mstart = moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
var mPresent = moment(presentDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");
var mEnd = moment(endDate, "MM/DD/YYYY");

var nextDate = moment({
        year: mPresent.year(), // get presentDt's year
        month: mPresent.month(), // get presentDt's month
        date: mEnd.add(1, 'day').date() // get endDt day of the month and add 1 day to it
    });

    var TESTING = nextDate;
    var end1date = mEnd;

    var array = [];
    var i = 0;
    while (1 === 1) {
      var nextStart = TESTING.clone().add(i, 'M');
      var nextEnd = TESTING.clone().add(i + 1, 'M') > end1date ? end1date : TESTING.clone().add(i + 1, 'M');
      array.push(nextEnd.diff(nextStart, 'days'));
      if (nextEnd >= end1date) {
          break;
      }
      i += 1;
    }

console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

What am i doing wrong here? It returns the date however, my screen just crashes. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

**Update:** The nextDate is being returned as NaN. I have moment 2.22.2 script but it's not working on my local machine.

The date is being picked from the date picker and i am not sure if that is why it doesn't set it properly. Changin the format if date from `moment(startDate, "MM/DD/YYYY")` to `moment(startDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY");` doesn't return invalid date anymore but i am not able to set the nextDate.

[image]

Comment: Where is NaN returned? I can't see any return statement.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev on array.push

Comment: Re `while (1 === 1) {`: Just FWIW, `while (true)` is shorter and more idiomatic. `while (1)` is also common, though more so in C than in JavaScript.

Comment: I usually see `while(true)`

Comment: Re `presentDate`, I take it back, apologies: `DD` matches single-digit date parts per [the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: Array.push doesn't return NaN.  Check the values of nextStart/nextEnd, one of those could be NaN or undefined or otherwise broken.

Comment: @James for some reason it returns NAN for nextDate but i have the right moment script.

Comment: OK I changed your code into a snippet and added the moment library version you are using, and I added a console.log(array) at the end.  It's not producing NaN as far as I can tell.  What's the problem here?

Comment: You are modifying mEnd by adding 1 day to it, by the way.

Comment: @James Yes. It is supposed to be that way. It returns Invalid Date in my local machine whereas it is working fine in the console here.

Comment: @James Just updated my post with the error message.

Comment: If we're not reproducing it here there's little we can do to help.